# html/css/jquery click through elements and all trigger events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Assuming that I have 1 button "Red" and multiple buttons behind:

```
<button type="button">Red</button>
<button type="button">ABC</button>
<button type="button">DEF</button>
<button type="button">GHI</button>
<button type="button">JKL</button>
```

Somehow, they are stacked on each others. But button "Red" is on top.

[image]

Would it be possible that clicking on "Red" will trigger events **on itself** and **on all buttons behind**?

Using CSS `"pointer-events:none;"` therefore doesn't work here. As well this is a general case, so using jQuery selectors to manually select and trigger them should be ruled out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)** to trigger the click event of `green` and `blue` button when you click on `red`button:

```
$('button.red').click(function () {
    $('button.green').trigger('click'); // or .click()
    $('button.blue').trigger('click'); // or .click()
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbPHL/1/)**

Comment: Well, I should rephrase my question as: Let's say I have a red button on top, and many other elements behind which I don't know. I just simply want that when I click the red button, the action will apply to it as well as transfer to all the other elements behind.

Comment: @tommyogp .You can use siblings selector. $("button.red").siblings().trigger("click");

Comment: @tommyogp You can use: $("button.red").siblings('button').trigger("click"); You can read more about `siblings()` from: http://api.jquery.com/siblings/

Answer (score 0):

Try putting them in css class. If you want to use javascript jquery, do .click() and activate all of them